# Maximum sum of hourglass in an array

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, c++11

I am solving some questions on HackerRank for practice purposes. This morning I solved one called [Maximum sum of hourglass in an array](http://hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array/problem).

*Given an array:*

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

the hourglass sum is 7 and we need to find the maximum sum of all hourglass in an array.

My implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using std::vector;

int hourglassSum(vector<vector<int>> &arr) {
    int highestSum = INT_MIN;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < arr.size() - 1; ++i) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (size_t j = 1; j < arr.at(i).size() - 1; ++j) {
            sum = arr.at(i - 1).at(j - 1) +
                  arr.at(i - 1).at(j) +
                  arr.at(i - 1).at(j + 1) +
                  arr.at(i).at(j) +
                  arr.at(i + 1).at(j - 1) +
                  arr.at(i + 1).at(j) +
                  arr.at(i + 1).at(j + 1);
            if (sum > highestSum) {
                highestSum = sum;
            }
        }
    }
    return highestSum;
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> nums = 
        {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, // 0
         {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // 1
         {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, // 2
         {0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0}, // 3
         {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}, // 4
         {0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0}}; // 5
    vector<vector<int>> nums2 = 
        {{0, -4, -6, 0, -7, -6},
         {-1, -2, -6, -8, -3, -1},
         {-8, -4, -2, -8, -8, -6},
         {-3, -1, -2, -5, -7, -4},
         {-3, -5, -3, -6, -6, -6},
         {-3, -6, 0, -8, -6, -7}};
    std::cout << hourglassSum(nums) << std::endl;  // expected 19
    std::cout << hourglassSum(nums2) << std::endl;  // expected -19
}
```

My questions:

1. I think the runtime of this code is O(n*m), does anyone think there is a better way of doing this?
2. Does the code look efficient and readable?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you had more hourglass example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Readability

The vector initialization in `main` would be more readable if the `{{` and `}}` were broken out onto separate lines.

```
    vector<vector<int>> nums = {
        {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, // 0
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // 1
        {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, // 2
        {0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0}, // 3
        {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}, // 4
        {0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0}
    }; // 5
    vector<vector<int>> nums2 =
    {
         {0, -4, -6, 0, -7, -6},
         {-1, -2, -6, -8, -3, -1},
         {-8, -4, -2, -8, -8, -6},
         {-3, -1, -2, -5, -7, -4},
         {-3, -5, -3, -6, -6, -6},
         {-3, -6, 0, -8, -6, -7}
    };
```

### Complexity

The function `int hourglassSum(vector<vector<int>> &arr)` is too complex (does too much) it would be better if it was 2 functions:

```
int singleHourglassSum(vector<vector<int>> &arr, size_t i, size_t j)
{
    int hourglassSum =
            arr.at(i - 1).at(j - 1) +
            arr.at(i - 1).at(j) +
            arr.at(i - 1).at(j + 1) +
            arr.at(i).at(j) +
            arr.at(i + 1).at(j - 1) +
            arr.at(i + 1).at(j) +
            arr.at(i + 1).at(j + 1);

    return  hourglassSum;
}

int maxHourglassSum(vector<vector<int>> &arr) {
    int highestSum = INT_MIN;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < arr.size() - 1; ++i) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (size_t j = 1; j < arr.at(i).size() - 1; ++j) {
            sum = singleHourglassSum(arr, i, j);
            if (sum > highestSum) {
                highestSum = sum;
            }
        }
    }
    return highestSum;
}
```

Keep in mind the Single Responsibility Principle:

The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you, I will keep the principle in mind.